# What language is this? I would like to know the resulting URL

Tags: c, url

I was wondering what compiler I should use for this code, I already tried C, Python and Swift. Swift told me it was a C-programming language.

```
s = ' '
a = '1112031584'
for (i = 1; i < length(a) ; i++) {
  if (a[i] % 2 == a[i-1] % 2)  {
    s += max(a[i], a[i-1])
  }
}
goto_url('www.multisoft.se/' + s)
```

I found it in an ad for a company called Multisoft. I really want to know where the resulting URL takes me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It can be easily adapted in C (just fix few syntax errors and missing declarations). Otherwise looks like some non-existent language (but I don't know all of them of course).

Comment: With the absence of semicolons, I wonder if it is [Go](https://go.dev/)?

Comment: Almost certainly the ad is just C-like pseudo-code. Your meant to "run" it with your brain.

Comment: Here you go: https://ideone.com/DAKDwY , the resulting URL is correct, just checked. I guess I can have the cookie.

Comment: But what about the initial space in `s`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Doesn't work with space... I guess it is a sloppy pseudocode

Comment: or it's a transcription typo.

Comment: Assuming you define `length`, `max`, and `goto_url` is this syntactically correct, albeit terrible JavaScript.

Comment: This is valid JS, were you to provide `length`, `max` and `goto_url`.

Comment: hmm that would be `a.length` in JS.

Comment: I think it's _pseudo code_ to let the person solving the task choose whatever language he/she feels most comfortable with

Comment: The solution is an oblong number by a long shot, but the code is incorrect: `s = ' '` should be `s = ''`. If you leave a space, you get a 404 error page.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid JavaScript, were you to provide `length`, `max` and `goto_url`. With small additional changes, it's also valid C, Perl, Java, ...

But it's probably not meant to be any one specific language. Rather, it's surely pseudocode any programmer should find understandable. It has a "C-like" syntax since a large number of languages do.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a specific language, it is a pseudocode. Below is given the C version to execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int max(int a, int b) {
        return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main(void)
{

char s[20];
char a[] = "1112031584";
int i=0;
int j=0;

for (i = 1; i < strlen(a) ; i++) {
  if (a[i] % 2 == a[i-1] % 2)  {
        s[j]=max(a[i],a[i-1]);
        j++;
        }
}
printf(" The link is : www.multisoft.se/%s ",s );
//goto_url('www.multisoft.se/' + s);
}
```

Comment: This looks almost exact copy of the code I provided in the comment. Except that it is not valid, because the resulting string is not null-terminated.